# Stopped to put petrol in my car drove out the garage went 3 mile car cut now wont start

Tags: vauxhall, astra

I stopped to put petrol in my car.

Put unleaded petrol in my car, left the garage. I drove the car about 3 miles and then it just stopped running. Now it will not start.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You can press the "caps lock" key once to turn off caps lock.

Comment: Does the engine turn over at all? (Does it crank?)

Comment: Perhaps you can give us more data? The exact model would be helpful. Is it a diesel engine?

Comment: Please use this reference to optimize your question: http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/helping-our-new-users-make-the-transition

Comment: Check your codes.  Check if the immobilizer has been activated.

Answer (score 3):

Check the receipt from the garage to ensure it really was unleaded petrol that you purchased.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've not put unleaded into a diesel? Was the vehicle almost out of fuel when you topped up. If so it could be an air lock somewhere in the fuel system. 
Also perhaps bad fuel from the garage,  it does happen.

Comment: ...Yeah exactly :)  Or water perhaps LOL.  Or a bad fuel filter all of a sudden.